# How to add bottom padding in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Got a link that got a span, inside that span I will from jquery add a number of news. But I want it to be smaller and with a bit of padding so it looks like a notification on a app?

This is the code I got:

```
<a id="menyNavOptions" href="nyheter.php" >Nyheter<span style="margin-bottom: 30px; font-size: 0.8em;font-weight:bolder ; color: #ff0000!important; line-height:0.3em;" id="outPost"></span></a>
```

So the look I am going for is a Link with a number on the top right corner

Thanks

Comment: can you explain more *it looks like a notification on a app* with an image or something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display:block` won't help, because it will have the full width (100%). Use `display:inline-block;`    
 
http://jsfiddle.net/M5TKv/

But I'm not sure if Padding bottom will do what you want.

**I think you want to do this:** 

http://jsfiddle.net/M5TKv/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try add display:inline-block in the CSS and it should behave as you expect :)

But I would rather use position relative on the link and position absolute on the span.

```
.linkclass {
    position: relative;
}
.spanclass {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: That only made the rest of the nav skip down a line

Comment: Updated, meant inline-block. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! I have to run it online with wordpress later, but thanks :) Hope it works good ! but it does not mess up my nav :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block; float: right;`